# Python: Returning Results From Another File

Tags: python, function, module

Having problems trying to return results with arguments in from another file "calcFun" to "Main". I'm able to enter all my x,y,z values, just don't get anything back from Calc in "calcFun" I have tried

```
print calcFun.Calc(x1Coordinates, x2Coordinates, y1Coordinates, y2Coordinates,
           z1Coordinates, z2Coordinates)
```

in main, but it tells me this is not defined.

**Main**

```
import calcFun

calcFun.Header()

doAnother = 'y'
while doAnother.lower() == 'y':

# functions to ask user to enter information to calulate 3 dimensional points
calcFun.GetX1()
calcFun.GetX2()
calcFun.GetY1()
calcFun.GetY2()
calcFun.GetZ1()
calcFun.GetZ2()

print calcFun.Calc(x1Coordinates, x2Coordinates, y1Coordinates, y2Coordinates,
           z1Coordinates, z2Coordinates)

doAnother = raw_input('\nCalulate another? (y/n) ')
print ('Good Bye!')
```

**calcFun**

```
import math

# -----Functions-----

# Header
def Header():
    print "Header"

# X1 Coordinates
def GetX1():
    x1Coordinates = input('Enter x1 Coordinate: Example. 2 ')
    return x1Coordinates

# X2 Coordinates
def GetX2():
    x2Coordinates = input('Enter x2 Coordinate: Example. 5 ')
    return x2Coordinates

# Y1 Coordinates
def GetY1():
    y1Coordinates = input('Enter y1 Coordinates: Example. 5 ')
    return y1Coordinates

# Y2 Coordinates
def GetY2():
    y2Coordinates = input('Enter y2 Coordinates: Example. 4 ')
    return y2Coordinates

# Z1 Coordinates
def GetZ1():
    z1Coordinates = input('Enter z1 Coordinates: Example. 7 ')
    return z1Coordinates

# Z2 Coordinates
def GetZ2():
    z2Coordinates = input('Enter z2 Coordinates: Example. 9 ')
    return z2Coordinates

# Calc Function
    # Calc will take x1Coordinates, x2Coordinates, y1Coordinates,
    # y2Coordinates, z1Coordinates and z2Coordinates as parameters.

def Calc(x1Coordinates, x2Coordinates, y1Coordinates, y2Coordinates,
               z1Coordinates, z2Coordinates):

    # Step 1: x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2 to the 2nd power & subtracting them
    x = (x2Coordinates - x1Coordinates)**2
    y = (y2Coordinates - y1Coordinates)**2
    z = (z2Coordinates - z1Coordinates)**2

    # Step 2: Adding x, y, z
    xyzTotal = x + y + z

    # Step 3: Square Rooting xyzTotal
    answer = math.sqrt(xyzTotal)

    # Calc returns summary of calulations
    resultStr = '\nx1 Coordinates: ' + str(x1Coordinates)
    resultStr += '\nx2 Coordinates: ' + str(x2Coordinates)    
    resultStr += '\n\ny1 Coordinates: ' + str(y1Coordinates)
    resultStr += '\ny2 Coordinates: ' + str(y2Coordinates)
    resultStr += '\n\nz1 Coordinates: ' + str(z1Coordinates)
    resultStr += '\nz2 Coordinates: ' + str(z2Coordinates)
    resultStr += '\nAnswer: '+ format(answer,'.2f')
    return resultStr
```

Comment: I've already done import calcFun and it asks me for the values, it just that it doesn't return any of the calculations.

Comment: What, exactly, does `Calc` return? Does it just print stuff?

Comment: returns what I entered and the answer.

Comment: I'm still not clear as to what you're saying. Are you importing `x1Coordinates`, etc from `calcFun` into `Main.py`?

Comment: After I enter all my values for x, y, z I need them to come back to the user along with the calculated answer (which is not shown) But I don't know how to grab the 1Coordinates, x2Coordinates, y1Coordinates, y2Coordinates, z1Coordinates, z2Coordinates from calcFun.

Comment: Well, where do these coordinates come from in the first place? From `calcFun`? If so, just `import` them.

Comment: [after looking at edit] Okay, you have two choices: either parse the output of `Calc` or (the better way) alter `calcFun` to either a) have the coordinates stored as importable variables or b) have `Calc` return more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
calcFun.GetX1()
calcFun.GetX2()
calcFun.GetY1()
calcFun.GetY2()
calcFun.GetZ1()
calcFun.GetZ2()

print calcFun.Calc(x1Coordinates, x2Coordinates, y1Coordinates, y2Coordinates,
           z1Coordinates, z2Coordinates)
```

to:

```
_x1 = calcFun.GetX1()
_x2 = calcFun.GetX2()
_y1 = calcFun.GetY1()
_y2 = calcFun.GetY2()
_z1 = calcFun.GetZ1()
_z2 = calcFun.GetZ2()

print calcFun.Calc(_x1, _x2, _y1, _y2, _z1, _z2)
```

Then I recommend reading up on exactly how python code gets interpreted ;p
In short, you were calling functions to get the variables from the user, but the values were not going anywhere.  The changes above will save the values into the variables (_x1, _x2, ...) which are then passed to the function call below.

Comment: This worked! My teacher didn't show us the right way then. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, no problem.  Glad to help. You can actually even just do "print calcFun.Calc(calcFun.GetX1(), calcFun.GetX2(), ... )" in one line rather than use variables at all. But it might not be very readable or reusable that way.

Answer (score 2):

You did not include much information about your Main.py, or the traceback message, so I am guessing a bit here.  Here is a simplified version of your problem, as I understand it:

main

```
$ cat Main.py
import calcFun
print calcFun.Calc(10, 20)
```

calcFun

```
$ cat calcFun.py
def Calc(a, b):
    resultStr = '\na' + str(a)
    resultStr += '\nb' + str(b)
    return resultStr
```

note that running works fine:

```
$ python Main.py

a10
b20
```

but if I try to use variable names 'a' and 'b'

```
$ cat Main.py
import calcFun
print calcFun.Calc(a, b)
```

this will give an error like you mentioned, but it has nothing to do with your other function or file, you are simply referring to variables that don't exist (you need to give a value for them):

```
$ python Main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print calcFun.Calc(a, b)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

this is the same behavior as

```
$ python -c 'sum([a, b])'
```

compared to

```
$ python -c 'sum([1, 2])'
```

As an aside, usual python naming conventions would have your files named 'main.py' and 'calc_fun.py' instead. See the relevant section of PEP8 at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names .